# Find object in array with fallback condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to find an object in array in the following way:

- get the first valid object
- if there is no valid object, return the object with the greatest version

The interface of the object:

```
interface Data {
    version: number;
    valid: boolean;
}
```

Sample data:

```
const data = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: false}, {version: 3, valid: false}];
// return {version: 3, valid: false} because there is no valid object and the greatest version is 3


const data2 = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: true}, {version: 3, valid: true}];
// return {version: 2, valid: true} because this is the first valid object
```

If I filter the array it works only on the second sample because I can't loop the array again to get the largest version:

```
data.find(d => d.valid); // undefined
data2.find(d => d.valid); // {version: 2, valid: true}
```

Playground:

```js
const data = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: false}, {version: 3, valid: false}];
const data2 = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: true}, {version: 3, valid: true}];


console.log(data.find(d => d.valid));
console.log(data2.find(d => d.valid));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just sort by your criteria and return the first object:

```
result = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.valid - b.valid || a.version - b.version).pop()
```

If you're afraid of this being "inefficient", you can also use a simple loop like this

```
function find(data) {
    let maxVer = data[0]
    
    for (let d of data) {
        if (d.valid)
            return d
        if (d.version > maxVer.version)
            maxVer = d
    }
    
    return maxVer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if a valid object exists with [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and the greatest version with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```js
const data = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: false}, {version: 3, valid: false}];
// return {version: 3, valid: false} because there is no valid object and the greatest version is 3


const data2 = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: true}, {version: 3, valid: true}];
// return {version: 2, valid: true} because this is the first valid object

function findFirstValidOrGreatestVersion(data) {
  return data.find(({ valid }) => valid) || data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.version < cur.version ? cur : acc);
}

console.log(findFirstValidOrGreatestVersion(data));
console.log(findFirstValidOrGreatestVersion(data2));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you close over a variable such as maxObject that keeps track of your maximum object, you can run `.find()` while simultaneously finding the max object in one pass of your array:

```js
const data = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: false}, {version: 3, valid: false}];
const data2 = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: true}, {version: 3, valid: true}];

const getObj = data => {
  let maxObj = {version: -Infinity};
  const res = data.find((data) => {
    maxObj = data.version > maxObj.version ? data : maxObj; 
    return data.valid;
  });
  return res || maxObj;
}; 

console.log(getObj(data));
console.log(getObj(data2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to find an object with `O(n)`, then try to iterate through array and check conditions using `reduce` method:

```js
const data = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: false}, {version: 3, valid: false}];

const anObject = data.reduce((a, {version, valid})=> {
  if (Object.keys(a).length == 0) {
    a[version] = {version, valid};
    return a;
  }
  let acc_key = Object.keys(a)[0] ;

  if (a[acc_key].valid) return a;

  if (version > acc_key) {
    delete a[acc_key];
    a[version] = {version, valid};
  }
  return a;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(anObject));
```

and another case:

```js
const data2 = [{version: 1, valid: false}, {version: 2, valid: true}, {version: 3, valid: true}];

const anObject = data2.reduce((a, {version, valid})=> {
  if (Object.keys(a).length == 0) {
    a[version] = {version, valid};
    return a;
  }
  let acc_key = Object.keys(a)[0] ;

  if (a[acc_key].valid) return a;

  if (version > acc_key) {
    delete a[acc_key];
    a[version] = {version, valid};
  }
  return a;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(anObject));
```